# logging onto an external drive from terminal

Tags: external-hdd

I have a seagate samsung external drive that I originally set from a windows PC.
Nautilus sees it perfectly well no problem, however, I cannot seem to get onto the drive using terminal. Further I cannot get fdisk -l to view all the drives so Iam unsure what it is called, when I type fdisk -l it just returns to the command prompt. 
In nautilus it is:-   sftp://seagate-3e8841.local/Data/rdl
This was copied straight from nautilus.

Comment: Thanks guys.Yes you are right, I forgot to say it is a hardwired network drive.

Comment: Please edit your question and include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the "sftp" command. In your terminal, type "sftp seagate-3e8841.local". It will try to log into your remote system using your current user name. If your user name on the remote system is different, then do "sftp user_name@seagate-3e8841.local" where "user_name" is replaced by the user name on the remote system. You probably want to do a "man sftp" to learn what commands are available.

You might also consider mounting the remote HDD using SMB.

Comment: Cheers thanks I will give that a try. I am not very confident on linux though so i do get a bit lost as to where i am in the system.